# asynctask in Android

Tags: android, parsing, class, response, android-asynctask

Can anybody tell about the "asynctask" used in android application. Currently I am working on an application where I have to create a Class in which I have to just get the response of any particular URL given.

I this particular class I was told to perform this task by making use of "asynctask". I had been getting very quick responses of all my Questions from here so far and I am greatly obliged to all of them who are helping me since my first question I posted here.

I am quite new to Android Programming and feeling a bit confidence by the community's camouflage with me.

Thanks,
david

Comment: see this tutorial about how to use AsyncTask in Android : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google's documentation for `AsyncTask` is pretty excellent: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

It's basically a construct that makes threading very simple. When you are doing something like making a web request to some URL, you don't want to block the UI thread. However, you usually want to update your UI with the results once your background task has completed.

`AsyncTask` makes this easy. First, you need to create a class that extends `AsyncTask`. When you `execute` the task, its `doInBackground` method will be called on a background thread. This is where you can download something from the Web or do whatever else you need to do.

The return value from `doInBackground`will be provided to the `onPostExecute` method, which can update the UI appropriately.

Again, I recommend checking out Google's documentation. They've got great examples on how to use this.